# Why certain css does not work on IE?

Tags: html, css, animation

Why certain css does not work on IE?

For Example: on this page, it work on chrome perfectly and it does not work on IE.
http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-loading-animation-loop/index.html

from the tutorial on this page:
http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/css3-loading-animation-loop/

I added some code on the css:

inside .ball:

```
{
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-name:spinoff;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

new key frames:

```
@keyframes spin {
0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
}


100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

}

Tested on IE11 and it is not working.
I am very confuse why it does not work on IE11...

**UPDATE**

It was my mistake that copy and paste the thing without realizing the mistake.
I had solved the mistake through the code below:

```
@keyframes spin {
0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}


100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

}

Thanks for raptor to pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Your CSS only has `-moz-` prefix, which only works in Firefox.

Comment: Oh, I think i know why it does not work, I missed out that thing. Thanks for pointing me out.

Comment: Please learn the basics of cross-browser CSS first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. It was my mistake that just direct copy-and-paste a new keyframes.

Comment: Check this post

http://www.markskowrondesign.com/blog/are-your-css3-animations-broken-in-ie10-and-ie11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the follow to give it support to other browsers and make it work in IE

-moz Mozilla
-webkit Chrome and Safari
-o- Opera
-ms Internet Explorer

and obviously without it for older versions or non famous ones